# Can't transmit packets in DPDK sample application

Tags: c, dpdk

I have set up DPDK 17.08.01 on an Ubuntu 16.04.2 system. I've followed the guides involving HugePages setup. I have set up 2048 HugePages (1024 pages per NUMA core), with each page being 2048 kB. This can be shown with the command `cat /proc/meminfo`:

```
HugePages_Total:    2048
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
```

I believe the `HugePages_Free` is `0` because I already started running an application on DPDK. They have no issue try to allocate `HugePages` as far as I know.

I have also attached the corresponding drivers necessary to two of my interfaces Here is the output of `usertools/dpdk-devbind.py --status`:

```
Network devices using DPDK-compatible driver
============================================
0000:01:00.0 '82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection 10fb' drv=igb_uio unused=uio_pci_generic
0000:01:00.1 '82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection 10fb' drv=igb_uio unused=uio_pci_generic

Network devices using kernel driver
===================================
0000:84:00.0 '82580 Gigabit Network Connection 150e' if=ens2f0 drv=igb unused=igb_uio,uio_pci_generic *Active*
0000:84:00.1 '82580 Gigabit Network Connection 150e' if=ens2f1 drv=igb unused=igb_uio,uio_pci_generic 
0000:84:00.2 '82580 Gigabit Network Connection 150e' if=ens2f2 drv=igb unused=igb_uio,uio_pci_generic 
0000:84:00.3 '82580 Gigabit Network Connection 150e' if=ens2f3 drv=igb unused=igb_uio,uio_pci_generic
```

I am trying the simple `basicfwd` sample application, which simply forwards from one port to the other. When I put in debug statements, however, I see only two loops for each port, and afterwards the application hangs. I am assuming the forwarding and whatnot is supposed to go on until the user stops it. Two packets are received in each port, but nothing is transmitted unfortunately.

I understand the issue is a bit vague, and related to `DPDK` setup, but any other help with commands to use for debugging, things I should check, would be appreciated, as I am a beginner with `DPDK`. I haven't been able to find any good diagnosing tips online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `basicfwd` example does not provide any statistics, so it could look like it hangs, but it fact it might work well.

There are few options:

1. It is possible to run the application with `gdb --args ./basicfwd` and confirm it receives frames, send frames or hangs.
2. Try another example applications, for example `l2fwd`, which provide some statistics.

Please also include logs, debug info etc information.

Comment: I'll try out `l2fwd` when I get the chance, but in the meantime, I did put print statements inside the main loop which calls the RX and TX burst methods. After a while the RX number seems to be 0, so the loop doesn't receive and then transmit anything.

Comment: Well, if there are no packets on RX, there will be nothing to forward. Are you sure there are packets on RX? How do you generate the traffic?

Comment: Don't mean to answer your question with another question, but how do you generate traffic in `basicfwd`, considering there's no stack as far as I know. Just realizing that may be the issue.

Comment: As a further point, I tried using `l2fwd`. Because there's no IP address concept, I added artificial IP addresses, and used `arp -s` to bind those to the hardware addresses that are listed when I start the application (on `l2fwd`). If I do it this way, does it matter what interface `ip route` is bounded to for this address (since the address isn't attached to the Kernel networking stack)? I am guessing something is wrong in this latter part.

Comment: @stoneman_41 there is no need to add any IPs both in basicfwd and l2fwd cases. Both of those examples work as a basic switch, i.e. forward packets from one port to another. In both cases you need to generate traffic using external generator. There are variety of options: 1) `ping -f` 2) `dpdk-pktgen` 3) hardware generator. l2fwd example has few figures about the setup: http://dpdk.org/doc/guides/sample_app_ug/l2_forward_job_stats.html

Comment: Thanks, so I got `pktgen` working independently (without an `l2fwd` application as well). Is it possible to run both simultaneously, since `pktgen` seems to open up `dpdk` as well and uses the available `HugePages`.

Also, in this scenario, how would you use `ping -f` w/o an IP address assigned? To clarify, I'd want to do all of this locally, on the same machine without VMs (for testing purposes).

Comment: @stoneman_41 packet generator or `ping -f` should generate packets which will go through the host with running `l2fwd`. So destination IP must be an IP of another host, i.e. `HostA -- L2FWD -- HostB` and then from HostA you run `ping -f HostB` Here is the diagram: http://dpdk.org/doc/guides/_images/l2_fwd_vm2vm.svg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163431/discussion-between-stoneman-41-and-andriy-berestovskyy).